# How could i find the text in a specific TD with a css class where TR is stored as this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this codes to loop through tr

```
 $('#prod_tbl > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                             var x = $(this);

              });
```

Now what i want is i have TD with different class names like .price,.name

I want access the value of each TD in different variable, when i loop through the TR

Like

```
     $('#prod_tbl > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                                     var x = $(this);
var price=$("td.price").text();
var name= $("td.name").text();


                      });
```

For each TR

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.find()` in this context to accomplish your task. That's because `td`s are the descendants of every `Tr`. `$(this)` will points to the `Tr`, so we have to use `.find(selector)` to find the matched descendants of it,

Try,

```
 $('#prod_tbl > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    var x = $(this);
    var price= x.find("td.price").text();
    var name = x.find("td.name").text();
 });
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to know more about `.find()`

Answer (score 1):

use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the `td` which are descendants of the current `tr` element

```
$('#prod_tbl > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    var x = $(this);
    var price = $(this).find("td.price").text();
    var name = $(this).find("td.name").text();


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently selecting all the td with class `price` and `name`. Pass current `tr` in context, **[jQuery( selector [, context ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)** or use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the td in **descendant** of current row.

Use [context in selector](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

```
var price=$("td.price", this).text();
var name= $("td.name", this).text();
```

Using [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var price = $(this).find("td.price").text();
var name = $(this).find("td.name").text();
```